# Why is this.props.children not recognized

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I made a small app in react-native and it won't recognize this.props. Here is the code in `let child = this.props.children;`

I have searched a lot of tutorials but didn't find a solution

```
import React,{Component} as react from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Dimensions,
  Animated,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

class TabItem extends Component{
  constructor(props)  {
    super(props);    
  }

  render() {
    let child = this.props.children;

    return (    
      // Code omitted
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove "as react" from your import statement

Comment: Can you post where and how you are using the `<TabItem/>` component?

Comment: What does “it doesn’t recognize this.props” mean exactly? I don’t understand how there are upvotes, there’s almost no description of the problem, there’s no context for the component usage.

Answer (score 0):

Search where are you rendering the component *TabItem* and then pass props from there as : `<TabItem {...this.props}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "it won't recognize this.props". I am assuming you get undefined for this.props.children. if that's the case, make sure your TableItem component has children and props are passed correctly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TabItem extends Component{

render(){
  return <div> {this.props.children} </div>
  }
}

const table = ()=><TabItem>Children</TabItem>

ReactDOM.render(<table />, document.getElementById('root'));
```